# Implications of almost sure summability of stochastic processes

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes

$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}\newcommand{\P}{\mathrm{P}}\newcommand{\esssup}{\mathrm{esssup}}$Let $(Z_j)_{j\in\N}$ be a nonnegative stochastic process ($Z_j\geq 0$ $\P$-a.s) for which the following holds:
$$
\esssup\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}Z_j\right)\leq M\tag{1}\label{1},
$$
for some $M\geq 0$.

Using the definition of [essential supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum) we have that the sequence is almost surely summable:
$$
\begin{align}
&\P\left[ \{\omega\in\Omega: \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}Z_j > M\}\right] = 0
\\
\Leftrightarrow\ &\P\left[ \{\omega\in\Omega: \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}Z_j \leq M\}\right] = 1
\end{align}$$
and since $\{\omega\in\Omega: \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}Z_j(\omega) \leq M\}\subseteq \{\omega\in\Omega: Z_j(\omega)\to 0\}$, we have that \eqref{1} implies $\P[\{\omega: Z_j(\omega)\to 0\}]=1$, that is, $Z_j\to 0$ a.s., and, *a fortiori*, $Z_j\to 0$ in probability.

I wonder whether we can prove that $\esssup(Z_j)\to 0$.

If not, there will be a $\delta>0$ and an increasing sequence of integers $(j_k)_k$ so that $\esssup(Z_{j_k})>\delta$ for all $k\in\N$. Since $Z_j$ are nonnegative, I guess (but I am not sure) that we can show that $\esssup(\sum_{k\in\N}Z_{j_k})>\delta$ which is a contradiction. Is this correct? If not, is there a counterexample where \eqref{1} holds but $\esssup(Z_j)$ does not converge to $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this need not be the case. For instance, it is possible that with probability $1$, there exists $j$ such that $Z_j=M$ and $Z_k=0$ for all $k\neq j$. For an explicit example, let $X$ be a Poisson random variable and define $Z_j:=\mathbf1_{\{X=j\}}$ for each $j$. Then $\sum_{j=0}^\infty Z_j=1$ almost surely, but $\operatorname{esssup}(Z_j)=1$ for all $j$, so in particular it does not converge to zero.

Note that the conclusion you are trying to draw - that $Z_j\to0$ in $L^\infty$ - is extremely strong. This is rarely something we would try to prove in probability theory.

EDIT: As we have discussed in the comments, it *is* true that $Z_j\to0$ in $L^p$ for any $1\le p<\infty$. To see this, it is sufficient to show that there is a constant $C$ such that $\sum_jZ_j^p\le C$ almost surely, since this would imply $\sum_j\mathbb E[Z_j^p]=\mathbb E\left[\sum_jZ_j^p\right]\le C$ by the monotone convergence theorem, which of course shows that $\mathbb E[Z_j^p]\to0$.

Let $A=\{j\in\mathbb N:Z_j\le1\}$ and $B=\mathbb N\setminus A$. Notice that $Z_j^p\le Z_j$ for all $j\in A$, $Z_j\le M$ for all $j\in B$ almost surely, and $|B|\le\sum_{j\in B}Z_j\le M$. This implies

$$\sum_jZ_j^p=\sum_{j\in A}Z_j^p+\sum_{j\in B}Z_j^p\le\sum_{j\in A}Z_j+M\cdot M^p\le M+M^{p+1}$$

almost surely, completing the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is it true, however, that $Z_j\to 0$ a.s.? Given (1), can we deduce anything additional about $(Z_j)_j$? (perhaps under additional assumptions?)

Comment: Yes, certainly - $\sum_jZ_j\le M$ almost surely, so clearly $Z_j\to0$ almost surely. As far as other things $(1)$ implies, you can for instance show that $Z_j\to0$ in $L^p$ for all $1\le p<\infty$. Try to think about how you might show this for $p=1$ (this is the easiest case).

Comment: For $p=1$ I would start by $\mathbb{E}(\sum_j Z_j) \leq \mathrm{esssup}(\sum_j Z_j) \leq M$ and use the linearity of $\mathbb{E}$.

Comment: Right. You technically also need the monotone convergence theorem since it's an infinite series, but you get the idea. For $p>1$, it's the same principle - we just need to find an (almost sure) upper bound for $\sum_jZ_j^p$, which i'll leave you to think a little bit about.

Comment: For $p=1$ we also have the Beppo-Levi Theorem which applies directly. Let me think about the $L^p$ convergence case...

Comment: I can only see that $\mathbb{E}[\sum_j Z_j]^p \leq M^p$, but this doesn't seem to imply that $\sum_j \mathbb{E}[Z_j^p]<\infty$. Any hints?

Comment: Use the same trick you would use to show $\ell^p\subset\ell^1$ to find an almost sure upper bound for $\sum_jZ_j^p $, being slightly more careful than usual to bound everything by a constant.

Comment: For $p=2$ (and similarly for any $p>1$): For almost every $\omega\in\Omega$: $\sum_j Z_j(\omega)\leq M$, so $\{Z_j(\omega)\}_j$ is in $\ell^1$, therefore in $\ell^2$, so $\sum_j Z_j(\omega)^2 < \infty$ thus $\{Z_j(\omega)^2\}_j$ converges to $0$ in almost surely $\Rightarrow$ in probability. In order to show that it converges in $L^1$ we need additional conditions such as uniform integrability.

Comment: You needed the idea for the proof, not the actual result. I have edited my answer to include the required argument.